# Struts 2 could not find a result for success returned from an action

Tags: java, macos, jsp, netbeans, struts2

I'm not a native English speaker, so my apologizes if I made some idiomatic mistake. I'm completely new on Struts2.
I developed a web project that contains 3 JSP pages, a deployment descriptor (web.xml), a struts configuration file (struts.xml) with 2 actions configured inside (an action named index and an action named welcome) and 1 class that implements the action logic for welcome action. When I try the index action it works perfectly but if I call the welcome action in the URL (welcome.action) I get the following error

```
Struts Problem Report
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   
No result defined for action actions.WelcomeAction and result success
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
...
```

Now I give you more information about the project and environment:

*Development Environment*

- OS: Mac OS X 10.10.3
- JRE: 1.8.0_20
- IDE: NetBeans 7.4
- App Server: GlassFish 4.0
- Server Location: localhost:8080
- Context Path: /AppStruts2Example
- URL Project: http://localhost:8080/AppStruts2Example/

*Web Project Development Information*

- Java EE Version: 7
- Struts2 Version: 2.3.15

*Code is described below*

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
  <constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="true" />

  <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
  <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="index">
       <result>/WelcomeFromIndexAction.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="welcome" class="actions.WelcomeAction">
       <result name="success">/WelcomeFromWelcomeAction.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

**actions.WelcomeAction.java**

```
package actions;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class WelcomeAction extends ActionSupport{

  @Override
  public String execute(){
    System.out.println("Inside of execute method in WelcomeAction.");
    System.out.println("Result: " + SUCCESS);
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Index JSP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Welcome to index.jsp!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**WelcomeFromIndexAction.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Index Action</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Welcome From Index Action</h1>
      <br />
      <h3>Current Page: WelcomeFromIndexAction.jsp</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

**WelcomeFromWelcomeAction.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Welcome Action</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Welcome From Welcome Action</h1>
      <br />
      <h3>Current Page: WelcomeFromWelcomeAction.jsp</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Project works fine when:

- I write directly the URL of anyone JSP on the browser
- I invoke the index action as you can see below: /index.action or /index -> both redirect me to WelcomeFromIndexAction.jsp

Project fails when:

- I invoke the welcome action as you can see below: /welcome.action or /welcome -> both shows me a web page with Struts Problem Report like described above

I thought it could be a problem with GlassFish Server, so I mounted a Debian on a VM and I installed a Tomcat 7 there. My next step was deploy the web application whit "Clean and Build" from NetBeans. It generated me a WAR file that I deployed into Tomcat 7 but I got the same problem. After this disappointing I disabled the Debian VM (Tomcat 7) and I come back to work with GlassFish 4.0

As you can see in WelcomeAction.java, it has a println statement within execute method. When I invoke welcome action on the browser, I can see that Struts effectively calls that method, the lines are printed on the output and after this call, when Struts2 has to process the Result then show me the error. This confirm me that Struts2 is not finding the result not the action, but I don't know why.

I tried configuring the filter dispatcher with old and new version of filter (FilterDispatcher/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter). With both i get same problem.
I tried configuring the welcome action in struts.xml exactly the same index action (practically by default) but doesn't work too. Only index action run fine.
I tried configuring the welcome action in struts.xml of many many ways, but nothing works.

So, here i am, needing someone help me. I appreciate your answers.

Note: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me post image because i'm new. So, I uploaded an important print screen to my dropbox. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101502868/NetBeans%20Struts2%20Error.png 
At this print screen you can see the libraries added, execution of execute method, the customized print lines and start of Struts error's.

Thank's.

Comment: your configuration looks ok.. may be you've an old struts.xml file being deployed

Comment: recreate your project with maven, because you might have wrong dependencies

Comment: Use Config Browser Plugin https://struts.apache.org/docs/config-browser-plugin.html itwill help you find mapping

Comment: @EliseoCastro to answer yourself, instead of editing your question, just ADD AN ANSWER ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The best way to fix this issue is using Maven** to create your project and manage all dependencies you could need. That was the only solution that works to me.

Here is an official guide to create a Struts 2 Web Application using Maven (very simple example): http://struts.apache.org/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-using-maven-to-manage-artifacts-and-to-build-the-application.html

**If you don't have installed Maven is OS X and you don't know how to install it, then follow the next steps to install it:**

Download Maven (This example uses Maven 3.3.3. The name of the compressed file is apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz): http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
Unpack the downloaded file (This example assumes that the downloaded file is located in /Users/YourUser/Downloads/). After unpack, a new directory will be created with the same name and path of your maven file downloaded. (In this example: /Users/YourUser/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.3/)
Open a Terminal
Move your maven directory to your home directory using this command:

mv ~/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.3/ ~/

Now, you have to edit the file .bash_profile located on your home directory (~/.bash_profile). To edit it, we'll use vi commando as you can see below:

vi ~/.bash_profile

Once opened you must press i to edit it

Now you can edit the file, so you have to write the following:

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export MAVEN=$HOME/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin

Close the terminal and open it again. That's all, Maven should be already installed. Use the following command to verify that Maven is working:

mvn -version

If you see the information about Maven, Java and OS X that you are using it's because Maven is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

make entry in struts.xml with custom method in action class named editUser so that control dirctly goes to that perticuler method and handle the result accordingly your logic

```
<action method="editUser" name="editUser" class="com.action.EditUserAction">
                        <result name="true">/jsp/editUser.jsp</result>
                        <result name="false">jsp/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And add custom method in your class instead of override execute method

```
class EditUserAction extendes ActionSupport{
                    public String editUser(){
                    String status = "false";
                        /**
                            do your buisness logic
                        */      
                    return status;  
                    }
                }
```

After doing same if still the issues is persist then check your configuration carefully